How to send correctly an email using System.Net.Mail
I was working in Visual Studio with Windows Forms. I added a method SendVerificationCode, to send the verification code using System.Net.Mail:
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace PasswordManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new();

        private void SendVerificationCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(textBox4.Text == "") && !(textBox2.Text == ""))
            {
                verificationCode = "";

                for (int _ = 0; _ < 4; _++)
                {
                    verificationCode += nums[rnd.Next(0, 10)];
                }

                try
                {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                    mail.From = new MailAddress("**********@gmail.com");
                    mail.To.Add(textBox2.Text);
                    mail.Subject = "Verification code";
                    mail.Body = verificationCode;

                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*********@gmail.com", "**********");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { 
                    throw new Exception("It's not working"); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The textBox2.Text was ********@wp.pl.
It throws an exception "it's not working".
Can somebody help me?
Thank you.

You're ignoring the actual exception and replacing it with the message "its not working", which tells you (and us) nothing about the problem.  You're going to want to examine the actual exception being caught.  This is a good time to start learning about exception handling in C#, how to catch and observe/log exceptions, etc.

Gmail no longer allows you to authenticate this way.

You're trying to send from a Gmail address. Gmail no longer allows simple username/password authentication. Until recently you could enable "Less Secure Apps" and get a per-app password, but this is no longer available*. Instead you'll need to get an OAuth2 token... which is not supported in System.Net.Mail.
That is, you cannot do this with .NET's built-in SMTP client.
Most people doing serious work have their own SMTP service. But for Gmail, there are third party libraries that can help. MailKit is one example.

* Technically this still available for some types of account, but it shuts off for good on Monday, less than a week from now.

For my gmail accounts, the "Allow less secure apps" was disabled June 2022. However, if a cell phone is attached to the gmail account, then you can continue using a username/password for authentication. However, the password is not the password to the gmail account, but rather a password specifically for the SMTP functionality. See: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833
